# Index.html is empty and showing 0bytes but webpage is loading

Tags: html, ftp

I am having a strange problem. 
I have index.html which is showing 0 bytes filesize in ftp(filezilla) , but webpage is opening normally as it should be . 
I made sure and checked again by clearing all cache and all. 
I want to edit the index.html but since its empty when downloaded from ftp , I cannot make any changes since its total blank.
I tried changing transfer settings from `auto` to `binary` but no use. 
Did anyone have such problem and any suggestion to fix it? 

this is my [site](http://www.refine-7ex.jp/). and here is the screenshot of ftp 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgiWi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to check the file size with ssh? When you are in the directory use the command

```
du -hs index.html
```

I noticed about other people having the same problem with ftp that have resolved it by setting the file transfer speed to a very low value like 10Kbits. The problem could be some kind of firewall that make the client drop the connection before it ends...

Comment: Yes you are right. I had connection drop. But I cannot login via ssh . Also tried changing the speed like you mentioned, stil showing 0 bytes. Shouldnt the website also be down? since the file is 0 bytes? like its totally empty.